# Adding a 0 in a Date variable

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Im doing a report via Reporting Services. One of my textbox have an expression that is receving a parameter that is basically a string that contains a date for example '20110410' and I need to convert this string to date, add the / and place the day first,month,year.

This has been done already. But the thing is that I need to add a 0 after the day and month when these are below 10, so instead of having 1/4/2011 I want 01/04/2011.

I dont know how to use the Tag code so sorry in advance if the code is not showing properly.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Uperiodo.Value = "Día",
IIF(Day(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate))<10,
"0"+Day(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate)),
(Day(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate))))
& "/" & 
Month(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate)) 
& "/" & 
Year(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate))
,
Month(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate)) 
& "/" & 
Year(FormatDateTime(
CDate(mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,5,2) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,1,4) & "/" & mid(Parameters!Desde.Value,7,2)),DateFormat.ShortDate))
)
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry I did not explain why we do this. We need to do this as the server where the report needs to be downloaded have an english format (mm/dd/yyyy).

Best Regards,

Comment: DateTime.Parse Method  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Is this VB.NET code?

Comment: parse the string into a `DateTime` variable (`DateTime.Parse`) the just use the proper format string `myDt.ToString("hh/mm/yyyy")` no need for all that horrible Mid and CDate code...though why is the `mid` function not capitalized? Is that your real VB code?

Comment: Use the Reporting Services Format function so this all boils down to a simple =Format(Parameters!Desde.Value,"dd/MM/yy") but make sure your parameter is defined as a DateTime before you do so.

Answer (score 1):

If this is vb.net like your tag says, you should really read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) on the classes that you are using. [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) will convert a string to a DateTime and [ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) will convert the DateTime back to a string with the format you want.

```
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("20110410", "yyyyMMdd", Nothing)

    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) ' 10/04/2011
```

Also, you should use [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of mid.
And if you have a number, you can append a 0 of needed.

```
     Console.WriteLine(4.ToString("00")) ' 04
     Console.WriteLine(10.ToString("00")) ' 10
```

Comment: `I want 01/04/2011` so the OP *probably* needs to use `ToString(hh/MM/yyyy")` depending on their culture

Comment: This report is going to be read on the reporting services server. The reporting services dlls are on the solution.

So it was my bad to put the VB.NET Tag.

Comment: @NicolasMendez I see you changed to asp.net, it could be C# or VB.NET. I assume it's vb.net in your case.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

I know the code is ugly and it was recently (1 min ago :) that I realized that I can use the "Personalized code" inside the properties of the report to do variables and such.

So the solution was using the & instead of +.

Best Regards and thanks for the help.-

Important Edit:
As a matter of fact I dont have to use an IIF, I just need to add the "0" & for the 1st 9 dates and that's it.